# What is the Localized parameters for in a WFFM custom save action?

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

The question speaks for itself. i cannot find any reason why you would have a localized parameter in a custom save action. Does anyone have an example on where that is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A save action item contains folowing configuration fields:

[image]

More informations you can find here: https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/the_save_action_item_fields

An example how to use it : https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/working_with_actions_and_validations/create_a_new_save_action 
 but it's not the best example.

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer but still i would like better examples.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this for some examples:
https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/working_with_actions_and_validations/fields/create_a_custom_field_type

The basic idea is to give you an option to have localized (in different languages) forms. That means you can have either localized Titles of your WFFM forms or the default values for the fields.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thnx @Pang for the review, however I did include the essential part of the answer and as a matter of fact I summarised what otherwise is a rather long article and thus I don’t see your comment and rating as valid.